# ROS / Point Grey Chameleon USB3 Cam / No Colour Images

Tags: ros, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I almost feel silly asking this, but I have sunken enough time into this now, and can't figure it out.
I have a USB3 Pt Grey Chameleon Camera, installed according to the ROS guide. Works fine, but by default it outputs a gray valued image. (It's a colour camera). Camera is plugged via an active USB3 5m extension cable into a USB3 port.
I cannot convince the camera to output a colour image.
I am on ROS Indigo on 64Bit Ubuntu 14.04.1

Steps taken so far:

$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pointgrey-camera-driver

$ sudo cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-pt-grey-chameleon.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e10", MODE="0666"

$ rosrun pointgrey_camera_driver list_cameras
Number of cameras found: 1
[0]Serial: 15374833, Model: Chameleon3 CM3-U3-13S2C, Vendor: Point Grey Research, Sensor: Sony ICX445AL (1/3" 1296x964 CCD), Resolution: 1288x964, Color: false, Firmware Version: 1.2.3.1

Not sure why this says colour:false, it definitely is a colour camera: https://www.ptgrey.com/chameleon3-13-mp-color-usb3-vision

Launched rqt with image view, all works fine. Can change the params like fps successfully with rqt / dynreconfig.
Changing the video mode on the camera via RQT kills the camera and/or my entire machine.

The default running mode of the camera is Format7_Mode0. I tried changing it to Format2_Mode1 ("1280x960_bayer8") hoping that I would get a bayer image to the debayer it and end up with colour. Doing so freezes the camera though, and power cycling usually doesnt help.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I use the roslaunch command as given on the ROS wiki page, and the debayer nodelet is happily running and publishing a /color topic, which isn't there when debayer is not running. The /color topic visualized in RQT is still greyscale.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231635/ros-/-point-grey-chameleon-usb3-cam-/-no-colour-images/) by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer to my own question:

I switched to a different ROS Point Grey stack from Kumar Robotics (https://github.com/KumarRobotics/flea3) that works for me. Seems that this stack is simply too old for USB3 Pt Grey cameras.

---

Originally posted by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) with karma: 70 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2016-04-11**:
USB3 Cameras are supposed to be supported. Perhaps you could file your issue as a bug: https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver

**Comment by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on 2016-04-12**:
Thanks, done :)

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2020-07-02**:
I get the same problem in `rviz` with `$ roslaunch pointgrey_camera_driver camera.launch`. there are three published topics to pick: `/camera/image_raw`, `/camera/image_mono` and `/camera/image_color`. Choosing the last topic does not visualize any image at all whereas `/camera/image_raw` visualizes grayscale raw image from sensor! Did u submit an issue on their github page?